# живой поиск на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

делаю на чистом js живой поиск и столкнулся с проблемой:в консоли ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: userItems.forEach is not a function
    at Input.oninput
```

```js
let users = [{
    name: "Артем :",
    number: 7911234345
  },
  {
    name: "Настя :",
    number: 7449234345
  },
  {
    name: "Илья :",
    number: 7932234345
  },
  {
    name: "Витя :",
    number: 7911134345
  },
  {
    name: "Антон :",
    number: 7917884345
  },
  {
    name: "Вика :",
    number: 7999734345
  },
  {
    name: "Игорь :",
    number: 7945634345
  },
];

users.map((item) => {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const Svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  Svg.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
  Svg.setAttributeNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
    "xmlns:xlink",
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/xlink"
  );
  const IconBox = document.createElement("div");
  const newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  const newDiv3 = document.createElement("div");
  const H1 = document.createElement("h1");
  const H2 = document.createElement("h1");
  const Item = document.createTextNode(`${item.name}`);
  const Item2 = document.createTextNode(`${item.number}`);

  H2.classList.add("wrapper__profilesItem");
  H1.classList.add("wrapper__profilesItem1");
  newDiv.classList.add("wrapper__profiles");
  newDiv2.classList.add("wrapper__profilesBox");
  Svg.classList.add("wrapper__heartIcon");

  div.appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(H1);
  newDiv.appendChild(H2);
  newDiv.appendChild(Svg);
  H1.appendChild(Item);
  H2.appendChild(Item2);
});

document.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "svg") {
    event.target.classList.toggle("--active");
    const Parent = event.target.parentNode;
    Parent.parentNode.classList.toggle("--Active");
  }
};

const Input = document.querySelector("#search");
console.log(Input);

Input.oninput = function() {
  let val = this.value.trim();
  let userItems = document.querySelector(".wrapper__items div");
  console.log(userItems);
  if (val != "") {
    userItems.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (elem.innerText.search(val == -1)) {
        elem.classList.add("hide");
        console.log(elem.innerText);
      } else {
        elem.classList.add("hide");
      }
    });
  } else {
    userItems.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove("hide");
    });
  }
};
```

```css
.wrapper {

    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper__header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper__input {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin: 10px;
}


.wrapper__body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper__items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper__profiles {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    column-gap: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 5px;
    user-select: none;
}


.wrapper__profilesItem {
    font-size: 29px;
    padding: 10px;
    user-select: none;
}

.wrapper__heartIcon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.--active {
    background-color: #000;
    fill: #000;

}

.--Active {
    order: -1;
    top: 0px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__header"><input type="search" placeholder="поиск" class="wrapper__input" id='search'></div>
  <div class="wrapper__body">
    <div id='div' class="wrapper__items"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelector  ---> querySelectorAll

Comment: Функция forEach доступна для массивов, запрос document.querySelector возвращает не массив, а элемент. Ваш `console.log(userItems);` должен был показать, что вернулся элемент DOM.

Comment: показал,я как то и не заметил ,так же хотел уточнить,поиск не осуществляется хотя в консоль выводиться текстовая информация блоков по которым идет поиск ,не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: Первая ошибка в if элементе `elem.innerText.search(val == -1)`, сравнение должно быть за скобками `elem.innerText.search(val) == -1`. Вторая ошибка, у вас в обоих случаях `add("hide")`, в ветке else должно быть remove: `if (elem.innerText.search(val) == -1) { ... } else { elem.classList.remove("hide"); }`

Comment: Так же хочу обратить внимание, что сайт позволяет создавать запускаемый пример, пользуйтесь этим. Если никто не захочет давать ответ, можете сами ответить на свой вопрос и заодно потренироваться, как это делается.

Comment: `let userItems = document.querySelector(".wrapper__items div");` в примере в блоке wrapper_items нет ни одного div - это надо учитывать

Comment: @AlexanderChernin они создаются динамически в коде сразу после вызова, поэтому на момент исполнения блоки уже будут присутствовать.

Comment: Спасибо большое,помогли)

Comment: @AlexKrass. я до сих пор не могу понять, почему все используют `add`/`remove` при булевой проеврке, есть же второй параметр у `toggle`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, раньше у toggle с параметром была хуже поддержка браузерами

Comment: @qwerf, если какой-то из ответов помог вам, то отметьте его верным поставив галочку слева от ответа. См. справку: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Grundy, а можешь пользователю в [ответе ниже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445000/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-javascript/1445229?noredirect=1#comment2582278_1445229) ответить на его комментарий?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, `userItems` объект.
А у объектов есть метод `forEach()`?

Если выполнить код

```
console.log(typeof userItems.forEach);
```

какой будет ответ?

```
undefined
```

У объекта `userItems` нет метода `forEach()`, поэтому движок и выдает такую ошибку.

Comment: Люди в комментариях и то более развернутые ответы дают. Если уж вы решили написать ответ, то старайтесь написать подробный и развернутый ответ.

Comment: Можете мне поставить галочку за мой ответ?

Comment: нет, я не могу, потому что я не являюсь автором вопроса. Спрашивайте у автора в комментариях под текстом вопроса

Comment: спросил за вас на случай если у вас не хватит прав и рейтинга для написания комментариев под вопросом

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста, почему был удален мой второй ответ на этот вопрос, ведь он же очень хорошо иллюстрирует, чем объект-массив отличается от объекта-объекта?

Comment: не могу сказать. я этого ответа не видел и у меня нет доступа для просмотра удаленных записей.

Comment: но если у вас есть доступ к удаленному ответу, то там по идее должна быть указана причина

Comment: Причины нет. Только это -  Оно было удалено 3 дня назад участниками Grundy♦. Самое прикольное в  этом, то что автор вопроса принял именно тот ответ.

Comment: Грюндий - ТОП1 участник по метке `javascript`, ТОП10 из всех участников сервиса за все его время существования, у него есть GOLD HAMMER по javascript, который позволяет ему удалять ответы единолично без голосования и помимо этого он еще и избранный модератор... Причины там не написано, потому что он единолично удалил данный ответ, но с другой стороны у меня нет пока поводов думать, что он мог удалить ответ без каких-либо на то оснований

Comment: Ну то, что у него есть такие права мне понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: оставил ему комментарий под вопросом. надеюсь ответит.

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошего дня вам.

Comment: @saverofPiter, была тревога, "не является ответом", которая была положительно рассмотрена.

Comment: нет, тревогу может оставить любой участник, который считает, что ваш пост не отвечал полноценно на  поставленный вопрос.